# Connect to SQLite (different server) db from JasperReports Server

Tags: sqlite, jasperserver

I'm trying to connect to SQLite db located on different server from *JasperReports Server*. Here is the error message:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_IOERR]  Some kind of disk I/O error occurred (disk I/O error)
```

Comment: sqlite is file-based. there is no "server". exactly how are you letting your app access those files?

Comment: @MarcB -I've created the shared folder where sqlite.db is located. For instance my sqlite.db is located on (\spicworks\db\spiceworks_prod.db) which is a shared drive. I'm able to access the folder from japersoft report server

Comment: Any help is appreciated? Thank you